# .NET 4 Website Thumbnail Generation

Tags: .net, asp.net, winforms, iis-7

I am trying to use the code available [here](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/b7cce396-e2b3-42d7-9571-cdc4eb38f3c1/build-a-selfcaching-asp.aspx) to generate thumbnail images of url's that are returned as part of a search function in my website. Everything works fine when I am running through the development server in Visual Studio 2010, but when I push the code out to the server (Windows Server 2008 64bit w/ IIS 7 running in Integrated Mode) the code never returns a thumbnail. Is there something I need to do to get this working in IIS 7?

Comment: I am willing to bet it is a permission issue with the absolute path.

Comment: I would recommend using a generic handler or change the permissions.

Comment: @Sunmorgus Might be a firewall, permissions... any info on that?

Comment: no errors being thrown, and no permissions issues that I can tell. the app pool is currently running under network service, but i've tried it with a domain pin as well and no dice. also, it doesn't use a path to save the image, it saves the image in memory so no need to write it out to a folder...

Comment: But the code you supplied is quoted as "with the images being cached in a "thumbnails" folder".  I can only diagnose what you supplied.

Comment: The code actually provides methods for both...you can provide a path and have it outputted there, or not provide a path and it is pulled from memory...similar to how you would get an image from a database and display it on a page...

Comment: I suspect it may have something to do with the Windows.Forms Webbrowser control being multi-threaded, which I have read is a problem when using it in webpages, but I also read that setting the apartment state (using .SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);) fixes that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the options, but what I ended up going with was an iframe that loaded the page with a div over top of it that prevented the user from clicking on anything inside of the frame. I couldn't find any solutions at all that would allow me to create the thumbnails without either installing something on the server (which wouldn't be allowed without a lengthy approval process for the software) or without jumping through a bunch of other hoops.

Also, I'm no longer with the company working on the project...so there's that :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ImageResizer](http://imageresizing.net/) that it is a open source IIS/ASP.NET module.